# javascript - array[id].method not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have a for loop running that goes through each item in my array and executes the array item with a method. For some reason this returns as undefined, though without the .method it works fine. Here's my code:

```js
    var people = ["susan", "david", "bob", "verity", "rhys", "charles"]
    
        function characters(name, sex) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sex = sex;
        }
    
    var susan = new characters("Susan", "Female");
    var david = new characters("David","Male");
    var bob = new characters("Bob","Male");
    var verity = new characters("Verity","Female");
    var rhys = new characters("Rhys","Male");
    var charles = new characters("Charles","Male");
    
    characters.prototype.info = function() {
        alert("Hi my name is " + this.name + " and I am a " + this.sex);
    }
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < people.length;i++) {
        people[i].info();
    }
```

Expected behaviour is that an alert that says "Hi my name is [name] and I am a [sex]" for each character but instead nothing happens.

Comment: Your array contains only strings.... It does not represent the variables

Comment: You have declared the function `characters` to be a constructor. In JavaScript there is a strong convention for using capitalized variable names for constructor functions, thus: `function Characters(name, sex) {//function body}`.

Comment: Some tips beside the answers already provided: `i = 0;` is best written with the `var` statement otherwise it will become an implicit global. Constructors are by most conventions capitalised, so write `Characters` instead of `characters` (or Character singular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your array is an array of strings and not an array of `characters` objects, which is what your loop is expecting.

`people[i]` for each iteration of the loop is not the object you've created, but rather a string containing the variable name of each object. Because of this, calling your `info()` method will be unsuccessful since you're calling it on a string rather than a `characters` object.

Remove the quotes and rearrange your code so that your array declaration comes after your variable declarations, and it will work fine:

```js
function characters(name, sex) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sex = sex;
}

characters.prototype.info = function() {
  alert("Hi my name is " + this.name + " and I am a " + this.sex);
}

var susan = new characters("Susan", "Female");
var david = new characters("David", "Male");
var bob = new characters("Bob", "Male");
var verity = new characters("Verity", "Female");
var rhys = new characters("Rhys", "Male");
var charles = new characters("Charles", "Male");

var people = [susan, david, bob, verity, rhys, charles];

for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  people[i].info();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you need characters inside your array, not strings. That's why it wasn't working. You were looping through string array trying to call their info function, but string does not implement info function. After you create your characters, you need to add them to the array, then you can loop through them calling info to get the alerts you wanted.

```js
    
function characters(name, sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
    
    var susan = new characters("Susan", "Female");
    var david = new characters("David","Male");
    var bob = new characters("Bob","Male");
    var verity = new characters("Verity","Female");
    var rhys = new characters("Rhys","Male");
    var charles = new characters("Charles","Male");
    
    characters.prototype.info = function() {
        alert("Hi my name is " + this.name + " and I am a " + this.sex);
    }
    
    var people = [susan, david, bob, verity, rhys, charles];
    
    for(i = 0; i < people.length;i++) {
        people[i].info();
    }
```

Comment: @CarlMarkham Well I was about to give an explanation. Just wanted to be the first to post the solution. :)

Comment: Racing to get the first answer is not the way helpful answers work

Answer (score 3):

`people` is an array of **strings** not objects.

Move this line:

```
var people = ["susan", "david", "bob", "verity", "rhys", "charles"]
```

so it is **after** the lines where you declare and assign values to the variables.

Then remove the quotes so you have variables instead of string literals.

```
var people = [susan, david, bob, verity, rhys, charles];
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious, thanks for clearing my head!

Answer (score 2):

`people` is an array of strings. There is no relation between the string "suzan" in the array and the variable `suzan` you declare further down. Instead try putting the objects themselves into the array:

```js
    
        function characters(name, sex) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sex = sex;
        }
    
    var susan = new characters("Susan", "Female");
    var david = new characters("David","Male");
    var bob = new characters("Bob","Male");
    var verity = new characters("Verity","Female");
    var rhys = new characters("Rhys","Male");
    var charles = new characters("Charles","Male");
    
    var people = [susan, david, bob, verity, rhys, charles];

    characters.prototype.info = function() {
        alert("Hi my name is " + this.name + " and I am a " + this.sex);
    }
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < people.length;i++) {
        people[i].info();
    }
```

You could even do that without all the specific variables for each person and put the result of the character-creation directly into the array:

```js
    function characters(name, sex) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sex = sex;
        }

    var people = [
       new characters("Susan", "Female"),
       new characters("David","Male"),
       new characters("Bob","Male"),
       new characters("Verity","Female"),
       new characters("Rhys","Male"),
       new characters("Charles","Male")
    ];
    
    characters.prototype.info = function() {
        alert("Hi my name is " + this.name + " and I am a " + this.sex);
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < people.length;i++) {
        people[i].info();
    }
```